# Manga where protagonist is isekai'd to a jungle world, returns after 200 years, and conquers the real world

Tags: story-identification, manga

I'm looking for a manga about this guy getting isekai'd into a jungle world. He lives there for a couple hundred years and then he goes back, and when he tells people, they don't believe him because there was no such thing as a jungle world; there are four isekai worlds, but only three of them are known.

He then basically takes the dungeons in the real world by force with his overwhelming skills that he learned over a couple hundred years surviving in the jungle.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: Also, if anyone correctly identifies the manga/manhwa you're looking for, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

It's called [The Druid of Seoul Station](https://m.webtoons.com/en/action/the-druid-of-seoul-station/list?title_no=3453&page=1):

> What started out as an ordinary day turned upside down when an unknown catastrophe struck Earth, transporting Suho Park to a different planet. He eventually learns how to adapt and fight for his survival in this foreign world, but one day, just as suddenly as he was sucked into this new planet, Suho is pulled back to Earth. He quickly learns that return to life as he remembers it is no longer possible, as Earth is in constant battle with monsters who’ve managed to infiltrate the planet. How will Suho fight against the monsters attacking Earth, and will he be able to survive this time with his current skills?

It can be read for free on WEBTOON.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by [edit]ing it to explain why you think this might be the correct manga, i.e. the ways in which it matches the one described in the question. It would help the rest of us to decide how likely this answer is to be correct, and whether we should therefore upvote it or not.

Comment: "Seoul Station Druid" doesn't seem to be the official English name, so I edited, also adding the description.