# Manga where mc is transported to a jungle world, became a jungle king then return to earth and conquers dungeons

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

"He lives there for a couple hundred years and then he goes back, and when he tells people, they don't believe him because there was no such thing as a jungle world; there are four isekai worlds, but only three of them are known.

He then basically takes the dungeons in the real world by force with his overwhelming skills that he learned over a couple hundred years surviving in the jungle. "

Taken from, [Manga where protagonist is isekai'd to a jungle world, returns after 200 years, and conquers the real world](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/263809/manga-where-protagonist-is-isekaid-to-a-jungle-world-returns-after-200-years)

When he first arrives, he got chased and attacked by wolves? And only when he protected the weakest aka youngest wolf cub did he end up becoming the jungle wolf king with the cub being his 'bff'?

Then when he finally able to leave that jungle world after some hundred years via a glow up crack in the ground i think? Upon his arrival on earth, he encountered a person who expected him to have magic or cool weapons but was disappointed when he didn't have any. They brought him to a hospital where he got continuously interviewed...as they don't believe anything in what he says yet expect sensible answers out of him.

He wields some big ass weapon? in the jungle world, runs around like Tarzan? He fights with bare hands, a physical warrior.. I'm not sure whether he managed to bring his weapon back??? He's like the Hulk??

Not sure about how the dungeons look but it could be like its an area blocked off by walls and full with building ruins and big creatures.

And, i believed it was in black and white. And I'm sorry if i may have unknowingly overlap some details with other mangas. But it's a jungle world.

Comment: Welcome back. If anyone correctly identifies the manga you're looking for, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: Do you remember about when you read this, and about how many chapters there were at the time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is *[The Druid of Seoul Station](https://myanimelist.net/manga/147489)*. It is available in English on webtoons.

> What started out as an ordinary day turned upside down when an unknown catastrophe struck Earth, transporting Suho Park to a different planet. He eventually learns how to adapt and fight for his survival in this foreign world, but one day, just as suddenly as he was sucked into this new planet, Suho is pulled back to Earth. He quickly learns that return to life as he remembers it is no longer possible, as Earth is in constant battle with monsters who've managed to infiltrate the planet. How will Suho fight against the monsters attacking Earth, and will he be able to survive this time with his current skills?

The synopsis covers the basic details, but the world Park is transferred to is essentially a jungle. He runs around naked, but quickly creates some crude clothes.

He protects a wolf pup while being attacked by a gorilla; after saving it, the rest of the pack adopts him.

[image]

The early chapters are interspersed with the interview with the doctor, where he tells his story and they don't believe him.

[image]

Comment: Thanks sooo much! I had so many of titles that i favorited and put in my read later that when i want to reread it, i just couldn't find it when it's right under my nose. Stupid me. I wonder what was the black and white ver story then... that's for next time. Thank you.